# How to add 1 to every cell of a range in Google sheets / Excel

Tags: function, google-sheets, range

I'm trying to add value of 1 to every cell within a range. Formula that I am using at the moment is:

```
=IF(AND('Agent 1'!C3=A60;'Agent 1'!C4=A61);COUNT(pon8_9;))
```

pon8_9 is the name of the range. This returns a value of 1 but only in the cell where this formula is written. I want the value of 1 to be added to every cell in this pon8_9 range.

I'm having a really hard time finding functions or possibilities for this.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/xz5h8p

Cells A60 and A61 belong to "pon8_9" range, it's marked by a blue outline.

I'm using data from another sheet (work shift). If someone is working a shift from 8 to 9, then I want every cell in range of that shift (from 8 to 9) to increase by 1.

But now while answering to Your comment I realised I might be using a completely wrong function (count).

So basically, I wanted to write a formula that would add +1 to every work hour of someones shift. There is multiple people working different shifts and it needs to track the number of people working that shift.

Comment: can yout share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result ?

Comment: yes here's a copy exported from google sheets into excel: https://drive.google.com/file/d/102nE31VPYo6HVkGrwfj0UHFCJ6YccFHB/view?usp=sharing

on the sheet number 2 called "Agent 1", you can choose starting and end time. sheet "raspored" takes this information and is supposed to store it into range.

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: try again (made it public now) and scroll down in the sheet because the "junk" is on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73, {{'Agent 1'!C3:C4;   'Agent 1'!C4 +"1:00:00"}, {1;1;""}}, 2, 1)),
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73, {{'Agent 1'!C6:C7;   'Agent 1'!C7 +"1:00:00"}, {1;1;""}}, 2, 1)),
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73, {{'Agent 1'!C9:C10;  'Agent 1'!C10+"1:00:00"}, {1;1;""}}, 2, 1)),
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73, {{'Agent 1'!C12:C13; 'Agent 1'!C13+"1:00:00"}, {1;1;""}}, 2, 1)),
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73, {{'Agent 1'!C15:C16; 'Agent 1'!C16+"1:00:00"}, {1;1;""}}, 2, 1)),
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73, {{'Agent 1'!C18:C19; 'Agent 1'!C19+"1:00:00"}, {1;1;""}}, 2, 1)),
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73, {{'Agent 1'!C21:C22; 'Agent 1'!C22+"1:00:00"}, {1;1;""}}, 2, 1))})
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Udw-GXY13Xu58YtpEr2p4lYWnWaQ6_50/edit#gid=1478282105)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73; {{'Agent 1'!C3:C4;   'Agent 1'!C4 +"1:00:00"}\ {1;1;""}}; 2; 1))\
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73; {{'Agent 1'!C6:C7;   'Agent 1'!C7 +"1:00:00"}\ {1;1;""}}; 2; 1))\
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73; {{'Agent 1'!C9:C10;  'Agent 1'!C10+"1:00:00"}\ {1;1;""}}; 2; 1))\
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73; {{'Agent 1'!C12:C13; 'Agent 1'!C13+"1:00:00"}\ {1;1;""}}; 2; 1))\
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73; {{'Agent 1'!C15:C16; 'Agent 1'!C16+"1:00:00"}\ {1;1;""}}; 2; 1))\
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73; {{'Agent 1'!C18:C19; 'Agent 1'!C19+"1:00:00"}\ {1;1;""}}; 2; 1))\
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(A60:A73; {{'Agent 1'!C21:C22; 'Agent 1'!C22+"1:00:00"}\ {1;1;""}}; 2; 1))})
```

Comment: this seems to work in your demo sheet. i get Formula parse error when I copy this into google sheets. I'll try to figure it out and make it work

thanks for now

Comment: @akristijan try the 2nd formula

Comment: It's working now. I marked your answer as the correct one. Thanks a lot